# Embedding image in gmail

Tags: python, matplotlib, gmail, embed, html-email

I have to send a HTML report as an email on gmail and it should be inline to avoid further downloads. I have written a python code that fetches data from database, does some analysis, plots graphs and all these results are summarized in a HTML table with one column containing images. 
Now, I have embedded these images to base64 to avoid any linking, but I later came to know that gmail doesn't support it and displays only the alt text for image.

I was generating the graphs using matplotlib and converting it then and there to base64. But now that this doesn't work, is there any way that I can send the report inline (with images) in gmail.

I have read some answers on stack overflow on using MIME but I am not getting how to convert the plot generated by matplotlib to a string(so as to avoid linking) and then after the report is completed (as a string), write that to a .html file and send as a message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely Gmail not supporting embedded images (as I *think* you say in your question). I've never seen it done in an HTML email. [This article](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) goes into more detail about what's possible, but says while embedding images works well in desktop clients, but...

> most likely not [work] at all in web based email clients such as Gmail, or Yahoo! Mail.